# Wooden dowel rod for wall hangings

Tags: strength, dowel

I'd like suggestions of what size (diameter) and wood type to use for a project I'm considering. I want to make macrame wall hangings that incorporate plant holders, so the rod would need to be strong enough to support the weight of the rope/cording material and the plants. A macrame panel 14"w x 30"l weighs approx 2 pounds and I estimate approximately 7 pounds for the planter/soil/plant. I'm considering making some that are three panels wide, so a total weight of approximately 30 pounds, preferably on a 48" rod. 
Also considering making single & double width hangings, on appropriately sized dowels, perhaps 18" & 36".

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE. We need more detail before you can get a truly useful Answer here. Just as in shelving the total weight is important to know but how it is distributed is also a critical factor, as is the number and spacing of supports. In theory if you had, say, three supports you could use a dowel *a lot* thinner (possibly half the diaeter) than if you only had one support either end.

Comment: The spacing for the supports is the most critical piece of information missing. The answer below seems pretty good, but if this is a 4' span with supports only at the end, a 3/4" oak dowel will bend significantly. How is the dowel being supported/hung?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using hardwood dowels. Maybe something like oak, and about the thickness of a broomstick.

I'm thinking 1" would be plenty thick. You may be able to use 3/4" and save some money, but I'd be afraid that it might warp over time in especially humid environments, etc.